# vb.net sqlite getting date from datetime that was saved as dbtype.string

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datetime

When I looked at the database record, the datetime saves like this: 4/6/2012 04:42:28 PM

because I've save it using dbtype.string

Now, I'm getting the date only, not including time, this is my code:

```
    Private Sub getpapererror(ByVal ddate As String)
    Dim sqlstr As String = "select * from perror where date(ddate) = $xddate"
    Dim sqlcmd As New SQLiteCommand(sqlstr, mycon)
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("$xddate", DbType.String).Value = ddate
    ...
    End Sub

    Dim xdt As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    getpapererror("#" & xdt.Month.ToString & "/" & xdt.Day.ToString & "/" & xdt.Year.ToString & "#")
```

I want to get only the date

Comment: You say you're *getting* the date, and that you *only* want to get the date - it's not clear what's wrong... (although you should be using `string.Format` if you *really* want to use strings). Why aren't you just using a date/time type anyway?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a date value as a string with certain format (like "4/6/2012"), you could look into [sqlite's strftime()](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

If you must save strings, maybe you can mangle the string afterwards. In python I'd try something like

```
>>> ds = "4/6/2012 5:55:55 PM"
>>> dt, tm = ds.split(None, 1)
>>> dt
'4/6/2012'
>>> tm
'5:55:55 PM'
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet, yes I want to use dbtype.string because it displays the exact date and time, not like using dbtype.DateTime it displays like this: 2012-04-06 18:57:26.015625, the time was not properly managed

Comment: @XenKid As said, strftime will make most any kind of output from a real date type.

Comment: Yes, I've used strftime, but it does get what I want: here's some of my code: Dim ss As String = "select dcash from paidpend where strftime('%m-%d-%Y', dtime) = $xddate", But that can't get when saved to dbtype.String